# Options for ValidationSet accuracy from NetTrain?

Tags: options, machine-learning, neural-networks

With `NetTrain[]` if you use the option `ValidationSet->Scale[.1]` it will run a validation test on 10% of the training data after each epoch. For example,

```
data = RandomSample@Table[x -> Exp[-x^2] + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, .15]], {x, -3, 3, .2}];
net = NetChain[{150, Tanh, 150, Tanh, 1}, "Input" -> "Scalar", "Output" -> "Scalar"];
trained = NetTrain[net, data, ValidationSet -> Scaled[.1]];
```

My question is ***how to get more information on the validation tests performed***, i.e. what was the set (indices of examples) and what were the metrics (precision, recall, ...).  And are there any (undocumented) suboptions that can *control the splits/shuffling choices* for each validation test performed?

Follow-up: is there any mechanism for breaking out of the training loop if the validation results start to plateau?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll add to our ToDo list the idea of having the validation indices be available as a property of NetTrain.

Answer (score 5):

I think for the `ValidationSet -> Scaled[.1]` the validation will be sampled with randomly from the training data. If we want to control the sample ourselves, we can split them manually and supply it as `ValidationSet -> testData`.

We can use the `TrainingProgressFunction` function to get more information about the validation accuracy, and abort the training after a certain goal is achieved.

For example, this will stop the training process once the validation loss is smaller than 0.1:

```
resource = ResourceObject["MNIST"];
trainingData = 
  RandomSample[ResourceData[resource, "TrainingData"], 6000];
testData = RandomSample[ResourceData[resource, "TestData"], 1000];
lenet = NetChain[{
    ConvolutionLayer[20, 5], Ramp, PoolingLayer[2, 2],
    ConvolutionLayer[50, 5], Ramp, PoolingLayer[2, 2],
    FlattenLayer[], 500, Ramp, 10, SoftmaxLayer[]},
   "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", Range[0, 9]}],
   "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {28, 28}, "Grayscale"}]
   ];

loss = {};
trained = 
 NetTrain[lenet, trainingData, ValidationSet -> testData, 
  MaxTrainingRounds -> 20, 
  TrainingProgressFunction -> {AppendTo[loss, #ValidationLoss]; 
     If[#ValidationLoss < 0.1, Abort[]]; &, 
    "Interval" -> Quantity[1, "Rounds"]}]

loss
(* {None, 0.474543, 0.290683, 0.174869, 0.146322, 0.110496, 0.109694, 0.0923467} *)
```

Comment: Nice answer. A hidden feature: instead of Abort[] you can also have the training progress function evaluate to the string "StopTraining".