# How to save the network at lowest loss?

Tags: neural-networks

For example:

```
INPUTNOTE = 1000;
Labels = RandomReal[1, {INPUTNOTE, 43}];
data = Transpose[{Range[INPUTNOTE], Labels}];
generator = Function[Map[#[[1]] -> #[[2]] &, RandomSample[data, #BatchSize]]];
net = NetChain[{EmbeddingLayer[128, "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Class", Range[1, INPUTNOTE]}]], 256, Ramp,256, Ramp, 43}]; 
{net, LossEvolutionPlot} = NetTrain[net, generator, MeanSquaredLossLayer[], {"TrainedNet", "LossEvolutionPlot"}, BatchSize -> 32, MaxTrainingRounds -> 2000];
LossEvolutionPlot
```

[image]

And I want to save network at the lowest point (red point).
How to do it?

***PS***：In *TensorFlow* this task can do like this:

```
min_loss_value=float("inf")
saver = tf.train.Saver()
for i in range(2000):
    ...train the network...
    loss_value = get_loss(sess,x,y)
    if loss_value<min_loss_value:
        min_loss_value=loss_value
        save_path = saver.save(sess,SAVE_NET_TRAIN,global_step=global_step)
        print("Training Set got a smaller value,network save to path: "+ save_path)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this is to check the loss while training using the `TrainingProgressFunction`.

This will terminate the training and give approximately the best net if the loss doesn't improve in certain batches:

```
loss = {};
window = 100;
INPUTNOTE = 1000;
Labels = RandomReal[1, {INPUTNOTE, 43}];
data = Transpose[{Range[INPUTNOTE], Labels}];
generator = 
  Function[Map[#[[1]] -> #[[2]] &, RandomSample[data, #BatchSize]]];
net = NetChain[{EmbeddingLayer[128, 
     "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Class", Range[1, INPUTNOTE]}]], 256, 
    Ramp, 256, Ramp, 43}];
{net, LossEvolutionPlot} = 
  NetTrain[net, generator, 
   MeanSquaredLossLayer[], {"TrainedNet", "LossEvolutionPlot"}, 
   BatchSize -> 32, MaxTrainingRounds -> 2000, 
   TrainingProgressFunction -> {If[AppendTo[loss, #BatchLoss]; 
       Length[loss] - First@Flatten@Position[loss, Min[loss]] >= 
        window, "StopTraining"] &, 
     "Interval" -> Quantity[1, "Rounds"]}];
LossEvolutionPlot
```

[image]

You can also change the window size and smooth the loss history a little bit to get a better location of the best net.

Another way is to save the net as we train the network

```
stepsize = 100;
{net, LossEvolutionPlot} = 
  NetTrain[net, generator, 
   MeanSquaredLossLayer[], {"TrainedNet", "LossEvolutionPlot"}, 
   BatchSize -> 32, MaxTrainingRounds -> 2000, 
   TrainingProgressFunction -> {If[#BatchLoss < minloss, 
       minloss = #BatchLoss; Print[#BatchLoss, "   ", #Round]; 
       Export["best_net.wlnet", #Net]] &, 
     "Interval" -> Quantity[stepsize, "Batches"]}];
```

Comment: Oh I didn't know about the "StopTraining" trigger, that's helpful!

Comment: @M.R. That one comes from [Taliesin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140164/1364) :)

Comment: if want to save net at lowest Validation Loss.`TrainingProgressFunction -> {If[#LowestValidationLoss < minloss, 
    Print[#LowestValidationLoss, "   ", #Round];
    Export["Target_model.wlnet", #Net]] &, 
  "Interval" -> Quantity[1, "Rounds"]}` will help